# Picking up image content from an email I get "undefined method `decoded' "

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am utilizing the [Cloudmailin](http://www.cloudmailin.com/) service for users to upload profile pictures from mobile devices. Cloudmailin will forward an email in the form of an HTTP POST to our site. They have [four methods](http://docs.cloudmailin.com/http_post_formats/) to format the post. I am using the [Multipart/form-data Hash Email Message Format](http://docs.cloudmailin.com/http_post_formats/multipart/) because I thought it would be easier to pick up the attachment data. In my controller I have the following:

```
require 'mail'
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

def create
  ...
      attachment = params[:attachments].first
      file = StringIO.new(attachment.decoded)
  ...
end
```

Error Message:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `decoded' for #<Array:0xb5060c24>)
```

I thought i might try using mms2r instead but in attempting to install the gem I got:

```
"Error installing mms2r: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension."
```

Rather than solving the mms2r problem I'd rather make a go of it without it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The attachments passed are a hash starting with a key of 0. You need to iterate through each using something like

```
params[:attachments].each do |key,value|
  # do something with value
  logger.info value.inspect
end
```

This should give ou access to the tempfile. In the case of the multipart format there's no base64 encoding. The attachment is just sent as is and accessible via file as rack will extract the multipart file.

Comment: Hey, Steve. Documentation says, "With embedded attachments the attachment content is passed in base-64 encoding to the content parameter of the attachment." I'm not using an attachment store.

Comment: I think the documentation is wrong. The content is definitely not coming through as base-64 in the multipart format. I think this is a mistake that was copied over from the JSON docs.

Comment: sorry the example was wrong. Writing it on the go wasn't a good idea! I will update the answer to use the key value pair correctly.